# What is the correct way of duplicating base class '__init__' signature in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

If a subclass does not define its own `__init__` method, the constructor of the base class (hence its signature) is automatically inherited.  But how one should define a sub-class `__init__` method that inherits the signature of the base class (automatically)?

For example:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

class Child1(Base):
    def foo(self):
        return self.arg1 + self.arg2


class Child2(Base):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.arg1 == 0:
            raise ValueError("arg1 cannot be zero")

    def foo(self):
        return self.arg2 / self.arg1
```

`Child1` does not have its own constructor, hence `Base`'s  `__init__` is inherited, and `help(Child1)` would give:

```
Help on class Child1 in module test:

class Child1(Base)
 |  Child1(arg1, arg2)
 |  
 ...
```

`Child2` needs to have a custom `__init__`.  However as it just passes all the arguments to `Base`,  its arguments are defined as `(*args, **kwargs)` so as to short-circuit everything to `Base`.  But this gives the following signature:

```
Help on class Child2 in module test:

class Child2(Base)
 |  Child2(*args, **kwargs)
 |  
 ...
```

which is much less informative.  Is there a way to say "I want my `__init__` to have the same signature as `Base.__init__`"?

Comment: Are you worried specifically about the output of `help`?

Comment: Because I think you might be able to add a decorator that fixes that for you, without having to type anything by hand every time.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have a more informative output in help and also in auto-complete hints issued by IDEs.

Comment: I'll play with introspection attributes and let you know. If you look at the attributes of a function object, I'm pretty sure you can copy the cosmetic signature pretty easily without modifying the actual expected input

Comment: I think I found a way that's pretty elegant

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is a description of how I figured out a reasonable solution, so please bear with me, or just scroll to the TL;DR'd decorator at the end.

Let's start by looking at what [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) is and does. `help` is added to the builtin namespace by [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html). The default implementation on my Ubuntu machine redirects everything to [`pydoc.help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html). This in turn uses [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to get signatures and descriptions. You are only interested in functions, and more specifically `__init__`. Also, you only care about the signature, not the rest of the docs. This should make things simpler.

We can safely assume that the signature you see in `help`/`pydoc` is generated by [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature). Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/inspect.py#L3091) of that function for Python 3.8.2, and tracing through [`inspect.Signature.from_callable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/inspect.py#L2840) -> [`inspect._signature_from_callable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/inspect.py#L2206) -> [Line 2246](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/inspect.py#L2246), we see a possible solution.

The gist of it is is that if a function object has a `__signature__` attribute, and that attribute is an instance of [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature), it will be used as the signature of the function, without recomputing it from the normal inspection of the [`__code__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) and `__annotation__` objects.

Another point in our favor is that functions are first-class objects with a [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) attribute that can have arbitrary keys assigned to it. Assigning `__signature__` to your function will not affect its execution, since it is only used for inspection. The actual runtime signature is determined in the `__code__` object through attributes like `co_argcount`, `co_kwonlyargcount`, `co_varnames`, etc.

You can therefore just do:

```
import inspect

Child2.__init__.__signature__ = inspect.signature(Base.__init__)
```

The result:

```
>>> help(Child1)
Help on class Child1 in module __main__:

class Child1(Base)
 |  Child1(arg1, arg2)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Child1
 |      Base
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  foo(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from Base:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, arg1, arg2)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

>>> help(Child2)
Help on class Child2 in module __main__:

class Child2(Base)
 |  Child2(arg1, arg2)
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Child2
 |      Base
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, arg1, arg2)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  foo(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Base:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Both constructors continue functioning as usual aside from that.

Since this does not modify the code object or even the annotations, the change is unlikely to affect anything with regards to the operation of the function.

**TL;DR**

Here is a decorator you can use to copy over function signatures without interfering with the function in any other way:

```
import inspect

def copy_signature(base):
    def decorator(func):
        func.__signature__ = inspect.signature(base)
        return func
    return decorator
```

And you could rewrite `Child2` as

```
class Child2:

    @copy_signature(Base.__init__)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: Interesting!  The question that I typically ask myself is if such a decorator exist somewhere in Python's built-in libraries?  (I assume the answer is no, as you seem to have gone through a large part of Python's code without finding such a decorator.)  And, if no, does that mean that what I am doing (not spelling out parent's constructor arguments explicitly) is bad practice?

P.S.  Many thanks for the detailed explanation on how things work.  I did not skip to TL;DR.  I would love to know exactly what's happening under the hood instead of just copy-pasting a solution :-)

Comment: BTW, I think `Signature` in your decorator should be `signature` (otherwise we try to initialize a `Signature` object from ` function`).  I cannot edit your answer --- SO complains that an edit must be at least 6 characters!

Comment: @kMaster. Thanks. Fixed. As far as there not being out-of-the box support, keep in mind that the annotation and inspection system is still quite young relative to the rest of the language. There are many features that are being actively developed even now. I don't see any "pyhonicity" issues with what you are trying to do. `*args **kwargs` are a very canonical idiom at this point. At the same time, copying the signature for `help` and  IDEs seems like a completely reasonable thing to do. I really don't think this violates the spirit of anything at all. In fact, I may use this decorator myself.

Comment: I think the real answer for OP would require `@copy_signature(Base.__init__)` instead?

Comment: @Grismar. Looking back at the original question, it seems that you're right.

Comment: @Grismar. I've updated the answer for clarity, but it really doesn't matter. `Child2` uses the same function as `Base` for its `__init__`.

Comment: This is pretty amazing and provides and answer to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997582/should-i-repeat-parent-class-init-arguments-in-the-child-classs-init-o?noredirect=1#comment130706480_73997582). But this is such a common requirement, that it seems crazy that anything custom like this would even be required.

Answer (score 0):

using functools' [wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) solved it for me

```
from functools import wraps
class Child2(Base):
    @wraps(Base.__init__, assigned=['__signature__']) # preserve base class signature for code completion
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just specify it explicitly:

```
class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        if arg1 == 0:
            raise ValueError("arg1 cannot be zero")
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Right, keep it simple. If you don't *know* the base class signature, after all, then how are you expecting to inherit from it and use `super` properly?

Comment: Obviously there was a reason for not specifying arguments explicitly: If at a later time `Base` requires more (or less) arguments in its constructor, the `__init__` of `Child2` needs to be rewritten as well.