# Should I repeat parent class __init__ arguments in the child class's __init__, or using **kwargs instead

Tags: python

Imagine a base class that you'd like to inherit from:

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

There seem to be two common patterns of handling a parent's kwargs in a child class's `__init__` method.

You can restate the parent's interface completely:

```py
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, radius: float):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y)
        self.radius = radius
```

Or you can specify only the part of the interface which is specific to the child, and hand the remaining kwargs to the parent's `__init__`:

```py
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius
```

Both of these seem to have pretty big drawbacks, so I'd be interested to hear what is considered standard or best practice.

The "restate the interface" method is appealing in toy examples like you commonly find in [discussions of Python inheritance](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/category/inheritance/), but what if we're subclassing something with a really complicated interface, like `pandas.DataFrame` or `logging.Logger`?

Also, if the parent interface changes, I have to remember to change all of my child class's interfaces to match, type hints and all. Not very DRY.

In these cases, you're almost certain to go for the `**kwargs` option.

But the `**kwargs` option leaves the user unsure about which arguments are actually required.

In the toy example above, a user might naively write:

```py
circle = Circle()  # Argument missing for parameter "radius"
```

Their IDE (or mypy or Pyright) is being helpful and saying that the `radius` parameter is required.

```py
circle = Circle(radius=5)
```

The IDE (or type checker) is now happy, but the code won't actually run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 13, in <module>
    circle = Circle(radius=5)
  File "foo.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Shape.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

So I'm stuck with a choice between writing out the parent interface multiple times, and not being warned by my IDE when I'm using a child class incorrectly.

What to do?

#### Research

[This mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10079) is loosely related to this.

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/omssdu/how_do_i_pass_init_arguments_to_a_subclass/) has a good rehearsal of the relevant arguments for/against each approach I outline.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626279/inheritance-best-practice-args-kwargs-or-explicitly-specifying-parameters) is maybe a duplicate of this one. Does the fact I'm talking about `__init__` make any difference though?

I've found [a real duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60952945/2071807), although the answer is a bit esoteric and doesn't seem like it would qualify as best, or normal, practice.

Comment: To address the concern of the scenario you brought up with more complex classes like `Logger`, this is where, to reference the article, you would leverage the adapter pattern. You would be protecting your code by creating that interface between what you don't control and setting something you do control that your own code will then leverage. This way it won't matter what does in fact change with code that isn't yours.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Because I do get warnings for these. I use PyCharm.

Comment: We can abstract away from IDEs by talking about Mypy, which is a fairly standard type checker. I'll update the question. @idjaw, can you find out which type checker is showing you a warning in Pycharm?

Comment: you are sending radius to Circle, then no other params, then shape expects x,y which are not sent, as `**kwargs` is empty: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html

Comment: @A.Herlas This question is precisely about the fact that the type checker is happy but the code doesn't run! I know _why_ the code doesn't run (kwargs is empty as you say) but I'm saying how can I get the type checker to acknowledge this fact.

Comment: well, I write code in vi...

Comment: What you want is not possible, you'd need the type checker to analyze the body of the constructor in order to check the parameters, that's not something type checkers do. If you want to share the kwargs, there have been proposal, e.g. https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/, I don't know if any has been accepted yet but I'm pretty sure none of the type checkers out there support this.

Comment: Not a canonical answer, but I would tend to repeat the required arguments but leave the optional ones to `**kwargs`. It's a half solution not digging to the real question, but a decent compromise in my opinion.

Comment: @joanis I actually quite like this suggestion.

Comment: The user can always consult the documentation. I would write your code independent of whatever IDE you are using. (IMO, clean code outweighs the need to help the IDE with clues that may not be necessary for everyone reading your code.)

Comment: @Holt linking to a Pep (or a Python message board) is definitely the right thing to do here, but I'm not convinced the PEP you've linked to is doing quite what I want. I want the superclass's required arguments to appear in the signature of the child class during autocomplete, type checking etc.

Comment: @LondonRob As I said, what you want is impossible. Because a superclass having argument X and Y does not mean that child class automatically have these, and the only way to get this information for the type checker would be to do very complex parsing of the constructors (from child class, parent class, possibly intermediate functions, etc.) since you can alter arguments before forwarding them to the super constructor. The `kwargs` typing is the closest you can get, but it's not fully implemented by type checker right now.

Comment: I'm coming around to @Oddaspa's idea but using dataclasses instead of pydantic. The generated `__init__` methods provided by `@dataclass` have all the properties you want, as long as all the constructor parameters and data fields. And if you need to do some post-init calculations, you can implement those in `__post_init__()`, which gets called after the data fields are initialized. For classes that cannot be dataclasses, I still stand by my original answer, but I'd also say use dataclasses whenever possible.

Comment: In fact dataclasses also offer init only variables, which are passed to `__post_init__()` but not stored as data fields, so maybe dataclass is the true canonical answer to your question.

Comment: @LondonRob time to award your bounty! Having read everything here, I don't know if any answer qualifies as truly canonical, but there are a number of good answers. Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the parent class has required (positional) arguments (as your `Shape` class does), then I'd argue that you must include those arguments in the `__init__` of the child (`Circle`) for the sake of being able to pass around "shape-like" instances and be sure that a `Circle` will behave like any other shape.  So this would be your `Circle` class:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(x: float, y: float, radius: float):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y)
        self.radius = radius


# The expectation is that this should work with all instances of `Shape`
def move_shape(shape: Shape, x: float, y: float):
    shape.x = x
    shape.y = y
```

However if the parent class is using *optional* kwargs, that's where stuff gets tricky.  You shouldn't have to define `colour: str` on your `Circle` class just because `colour` is an optional argument for `Shape`.  It's up to the developer using your `Circle` class to know the interface of all shapes and if need be, interrogate the code and note that `Circle` can accept `colour=green` as it passes `**kwargs` to its parent constructor:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(x: float, y: float, colour: str = "black"):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colour = colour 


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(x: float, y: float, radius: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y, **kwargs)
        self.radius = radius


def move_shape(shape: Shape, x: float, y: float):
    shape.x = x
    shape.y = y


def colour_shape(shape: Shape, colour: str):
    shape.colour = colour
```

Generally my attitude is that a docstring exists to explain *why* something is written the way it is, not *what* it's doing.  That should be clear from the code.  So, if your `Circle` requires an `x` and `y` parameter for use in the parent class, then it should say as much in the signature.  If the parent class has *optional* requirements, then `**kwargs` is sufficient in the child class and it's incumbent upon the developer to interrogate `Circle` and `Shape` to see what the options are.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as [joanis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74028312/2071807) but a bit more fleshed out. I'm happy to award the bounty here, but an honourable mention and thanks goes to joanis.

Answer (score 10):

The solution I would consider most reasonable (though I realize what I'm saying might not be canonical) is to repeat the parent-class parameters that are required, but leave the optional ones to `**kwargs`.

Benefits:

- clean code that is easy for a human reader to understand,
- keeps the type checkers happy,
- repeats only the essential stuff,
- supports all the optional parameters without repeating those.

Comment: I think this is a very sensible compromise. I'm going to upvote it, but I'll leave the bounty to see whether someone can come up with a more canonical answer, including maybe a link to this kind of discussion in a PEP or on some serious Python message board.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll be interested to read any alternative answers or canonical references, too.

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR

**In Python 3.10, dataclasses provide a clean solution**

Dataclasses provides inheritance mechanisms with automatically generated cumulative constructors that provide everything needed for mypy or vscode to do the type checking, yet is completely DRY.

Starting with Python 3.10, dataclasses are suitable more often than one might think, so I contend they could be considered a canonical answer to the question here, although probably not for earlier versions of Python.

#### Details

##### My thought process

I've been doing some more thinking and research on this topic, partly inspired by other answers and comments here. I have also done some tests, and eventually convinced myself that the canonical answer should be to use `@dataclass` whenever possible (which is more often than one might think, at least with Python >= 3.10).

There will of course be cases that really cannot be cast to dataclasses, and then I'll say use [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74028312/3216427) for those.

##### Augmented example without dataclasses

Let me augment the example a bit to illustrate my idea.

```
class Shape:

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, name="default name", verbose=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name
        if verbose:
            print("Initialized:", self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}(x={self.x},y={self.y},name={self.name})"

class Circle(Shape):

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, r: float, **kwargs):
        self.r = r
        super().__init__(x, y, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}(r={self.r},x={self.x},y={self.y},name={self.name})"
```

Here I've added the optional parameter `name` with a default value that gets stored, and the optional parameter `verbose` that affects what `__init__` does without getting stored. Those add parameters to `__init__` beyond just required data fields.

And I've already applied the solution I suggested in my first answer, which was to repeat the required arguments, but only the required arguments.

##### Solution using dataclasses in Python 3.10

Now, let's rewrite this with dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field

@dataclass
class Shape:
    x: float
    y: float
    name: str = field(kw_only=True, default="default name")
    verbose: InitVar[bool] = field(kw_only=True, default=False)

    def __post_init__(self, verbose):
        if verbose:
            print("Initialized:", self)

@dataclass
class Circle(Shape):
    r: float
```

Notice how much shorter the code is. `name` is still optional with a default value. `verbose` is still accepted as an initialization parameter that is not stored. I get my `__repr__` for free. And it makes the constructor of `Circle` explicitly require `x` and `y`, as well as `r`, so both mypy and pylint (and presumably vscode too) do complain if any of them is missing. In fact, being automatically generated, the `Circle` constructor repeats everything in the `Shape` constructor, but *I* didn't have to write it, so that's perfectly DRY.

##### An inherited init-only parameter

Let's add another init-only parameter, `scale`, which has the effect of scaling everything in both classes, i.e., `x`, `y` and `r` are multiplied by  `scale`. This case is a bit twisted, but it lets me require a `__post_init__` in the subclass too, which I would like to illustrate.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field

@dataclass
class DCShape:
    x: float
    y: float
    scale: InitVar[float] = field(kw_only=True, default=1)
    name: str = field(kw_only=True, default="default name")
    verbose: InitVar[bool] = field(kw_only=True, default=False)

    def __post_init__(self, scale, verbose):
        self.x = scale * self.x
        self.y = scale * self.y
        if verbose:
            print("Initialized:", self)

@dataclass
class DCCircle(DCShape):
    r: float

    def __post_init__(self, scale, verbose):
        self.r = scale * self.r
        super().__post_init__(scale, verbose)
```

This is a pretty decent solution too, in my opinion. I did have to repeat `scale` and `verbose` in both classes' `__post_init__` functions, and the subclass's instance has to call the superclass's instance explicitly, but this is still something I'd be happy to use in real production code.

##### Why not with Python <= 3.9?

To make this clean, I had to use keyword-only fields, which were only introduced to dataclasses with Python 3.10.

With earlier version, I would have had to also give `Circle.r` a default value, and then presumably add custom code to make sure that default value wasn't use, which would mean mypy would not notice if `r` was missing, so I feel that kills that solution. Although for cases where the base class only has required field, dataclasses work well before 3.10 too.

##### References

- [The `dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)
- [`__post_init__`: other initialization code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing)
- [`InitVar`: init only variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables)

Comment: I really like this answer. The more I use data classes the more I wonder why _all_ Python classes don't work like this. Presumably it's because you don't control the __init__, but so what?!

Comment: Well, really, the fact that you don't control the init is a feature, really, and now that I found out about `__post_init__`, it seems you can still do anything you might have wanted to do in `__init__` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is to use the `**kwargs` approach, but to also define a `__signature__` attribute on the class. This is a `typing.Signature` object that describes the arguments that the class expects.

```
from typing import Signature

class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius

    __signature__ = Signature(
        parameters=[
            Parameter('radius', Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, annotation=float),
            Parameter('x', Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, annotation=float),
            Parameter('y', Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, annotation=float),
        ]
    )
```

This will allow type checkers to understand that `radius` is a required argument, and that `x` and `y` are optional.

Comment: Nice. It would be even better to put x and y in Shape's signature and copy them into Circle's without repeating them.

Comment: On detail, in Circle's signature, x and y are not positional, they're only keyword, even though they were positional in Shape.

Comment: OK, I take it back: this seems like a great solution, but what version of Python does it work with? I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'Signature' from 'typing'" in both 3.9 and 3.10.

Comment: This is cool and interesting, so it gets an upvote from me, but I don't really see how it gets us past the fundamental problem: that each subclass needs to restate the interface of the super class. Not very DRY.

Comment: Is it maybe supposed to be `from inspect import Signature`? [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature)

Comment: OK, with `from inspect import Signature, Parameter` I got the code to run, but now I have a different problem. `c = Circle(3)` gave me the expected TypeError due to missing x and y, but neither `pylint` nor `mypy` reported the problem, so it seems they don't inspect that `__signature__` field, unforunately.

Comment: And the runtime `TypeError` was flagged not on the `Circle(3)` line of code but on `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, so even the runtime system ignored that signature field. (Testing with Python 3.9.12 at the moment.) (PS: I'm not criticizing, I just really want to figure out how to make this work!)

Answer (score 3):

I come from C++. In there this is OOP 101. But since I transitioned to Python, throughout my career I used this no matter how annoying it was to duplicate parent constructor arguments. Also I found the hard way it was very hard to debug with **kwargs with a large enough code base. So, based on my experience I will upvote **@joanis**  answer highlighting the benefits

> Benefits:
>
> clean code that is easy for a human reader to understand
> keeps the
> type checkers happy
> repeats only the essential stuff
>  supports all
> the optional parameters without repeating those.

Although if one needs `**kwargs` is an option, but as far as I know, type checking will still not work; i.e. a debugging nightmare. Python is after all, an interpreted language.

And if you analyse the problem a bit deeper, it makes sense. Python Object creation only looks at a Single Class name eg. `r = Circle(x,y)` . There is no way to identify what it is inherited from without looking at the class. Where In C++ we could write something like below, which is compiled, and then resolved at runtime. Python IDE's inform most of the error prior to execution. But I can see why its taken time to provide a solution to this particular problem since **kwargs essentially does not indicate any information that could be validated prior to a run.

```
#C++ code
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
class Shape {                                           
    public:    
    string x = "";      
};     
class Circle: public Shape                      
{      
 public:    
    string x = "50";      
};  
int main(void) {    
     Shape r= Circle();      
    cout<<r.x;     
}
```

Do I look forward to this in Python? Well absolutely, along with some proper Polymorphism like C++. But sadly as advertised these languages have very different mechanisms. To quote from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5314882/Python-vs-Cplusplus-Series-Polymorphism-and-Duck-T) "Python does not have the concept of virtual function or interface like C++. However, Python provides an infrastructure that allows us to build something resembling interfaces’ functionality" (Not a very well reputed site, but I found this quote to be noteworthy)

on the same line a comment on this line in the problem statement;

> Also, if the parent interface changes, I have to remember to change all of my child class's interfaces to match, type hints and all. Not very DRY.

I actually believe this is necessary! We should be careful not to change Parent classes after a bunch of code is written.

However, I recommend reading this "Learning Path Advanced Python Programming" by Dr.Gabriele Lanaro (Or any other book regarding Python Design Patterns) to know a bit about how you can avoid pretty much many pitfalls like this via Design Patterns.

Lastly, while this may probably not the complete and satisfactory answer you are looking for my suggestions are;

1. If the project is large enough, stick to duplicating class constructors without using **kwargs (The solution with **signature** was nice! I can't see how it can harm at scale too)
2. If parent class is library file or third party class consider using an Adapter Pattern.
3. Have look at Builder Pattern and something called Fluent Builder Pattern

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I searched a little bit and this is what I found:

1.-There are lots of libraries that can do the job, like [Makefun](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/), or [Merge_args](https://pypi.org/project/merge-args/), or [Python Forge](https://pypi.org/project/python-forge/), they all work the same:

Using inspect and/or functools libraries and trying to merge their signatures (they get all parameters by e.g `tuple(signature(your_function).parameters.values())`, or `getfullargspec(your_function.__init__)` (remember to slice it) and then replacing the signature.
Since they have put a lot effort in that task, I'd recommend you to use them if you want a solid solution.

2.-I had the same problem long ago, and I ended up restating only the most important parameters, and leaving the rest with **kwargs. But there's a better tournaround if you want something complete without any library (but not so DRY by my part haha): just use `print(signature(Shape.__init__))` (Remember to `from inspect import signature`) and copy what's useful to you :).

3.-I saw @cactusboat's answer and I came up to this too, hope it helps:

```
from inspect import signature, Signature
from itertools import chain
from collections import OrderedDict


def make_signature(subclass, superclass):
    """Returns a signature object for the subclass constructor's __signature__ attribute."""
    sub_params = signature(superclass.__init__).parameters
    sup_params = signature(subclass.__init__).parameters
    mixed_params = OrderedDict(chain(sub_params.items(), sup_params.items()))
    mixed_signature = Signature(parameters=mixed_params.values())
    return mixed_signature


class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius


Circle.__signature__ = make_signature(Circle, Shape)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    help(Circle)  # Circle(self, x: float, y: float, radius: float, **kwargs) ...
```

4.-As you can see, there are many ways, but there isn't any canonical one, the closest one could be [PEP 362](https://peps.python.org/pep-0362/#abstract), and it has an example on how to Visualize Callable Objects’ Signature. But it's hard, since you would be falling into the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Hope it helps! I'm kinda new into programming, so I did my best to find the best that I could. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to answer this question (which calls for opinions) from the point of view that you intend your code to be used.

For **you** as a developer that know the classes that you are coding, `**kwargs` can save some lengthy copy/pasting and refactoring if a superclass is modified. Meanwhile, you can use the method that you like most and even mix usage because you have full control over your own code. In the end, this is a matter of convenience.

For **dev-users** that will use your set of classes as a library, they will expect a fully documented API and your own potential refactoring work do not matter to them. So in that case it will be more intuitive to them to have the full parameter list.

For **lambda-users** that will just use your code without knowing what is inside it, it does not matter at all, but it should work no matter what. A general rule of thumb is to catch as many errors in the IDE while you can still fix it, not at runtime when it is too late. In that regard, `**kwargs` is more sensitive and is more prone to lead to bad user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io). This introduces a dependency which might be a deal breaker, but I think it might be what you are looking for.

Example:

```py
from Pydantic import BaseModel
class ShapePydantic(BaseModel):
  x: float
  y: float

class CirclePydantic(ShapePydantic):
  radius:float
```

Type hint:
[image: Type hint from inherited class]

Worth noting that Pydantic allows extra inputs extra fields (or arguments) by default, but this can be turned off by using  `extra=Extra.forbid`.

```py
from pydantic import Extra
class CirclePydantic(ShapePydantic, extra=Extra.forbid):
  radius:float
```

Comment: I think `dataclasses.dataclass` offers this too, without an external dependency.

Comment: @Oddaspa this is a nice solution for data classes, but doesn't answer the higher-level question, which remains relevant because not all classes are data classes.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this question... I like how both Pydantic's BaseModel and dataclasses provide all this nice automation with no unnecessary repetition, and I wish the solution could work with more cases. I just tested what happens if you try to add a parameter to `__init__` that's not just a member variable, you have to write the whole `__init__` yourself and repeat everything. *But*, the `__post_init__` can be used to do additional initialization without losing the generated `__init__` method, so that might still be a powerful solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky and depends on how you intend for your class to be used. For example if you allow usage of positional arguments then you get situation that you describe and basically break the expected order of arguments.

My opinion is that if you use `**kwargs` then it's better to prohibit use of positional arguments at all (notice asterisk before arguments):

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, *, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, *, radius: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius
```

This solves the issue of unexpected order but does not help the end user.

For that I would suggest to use [stubs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/). It's still can be considered a code duplication, although it can be generated for you (granted you have not too complicated code) and if needed can be tweaked manually. Besides that, it allows developer to provide better type annotations in complicated situations.

That way, you can actually even use any variant you like as a developer, as long as stubs match your implementation, even support overloaded initializers and IDE will show to the user which signature is applicable to their arguments.

Still, I would suggest not to mix named positional arguments and `**kwargs` unless there is a good clear reason for it (like generic decorators or some kind of proxy). Especially complicated things become when using `*args, **kwargs` combo, since client now can unknowingly pass in the same argument twice (if there are no type annotations/stubs). This forces you to handle such cases and write complicated "parsing" of arguments. Such an approach can be justified in a large and complicated interface and considered better, since, in a way, provides more flexibility, but for a small interface it would be an overkill and pain.

If using `*args, **kwargs` then stub file is a must in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not be the best practice, but if you want to avoid using the docstrings and want the IDE (type checker) to find these errors, you can use this implementation.

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius: float, shape: Shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.radius = radius
```

[image]

Comment: This breaks the polymorphism, so a Circle is no longer a Shape, it just contains one, and any class that expects a Shape object will refuse a Circle. So this is not a solution.

Comment: @joanis Yes, that is right, although, for an alternative approach, any class that expects a shape can be provided with the shape object of that class. I think it might be a solution for that.