# How to type hint subclass method with base class method hint without explicitly annotating it

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to hint that A has a construct parameter c is int

For origin code:

```py
class B:
  def __init__(c: int):
    pass
class A(B):
  def __init__(a: str, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

I can do it explicitly like:

```py
class B:
  def __init__(c: int):
    pass
class A(B):
  def __init__(a: str, c: int):
    super().__init__(c=c)
```

I am just wondering if we could have something like:

```py
class B:
  def __init__(c: int):
    pass
class A(B):
  def __init__(a: str, **kwargs: GetHintFrom(B.__init__)):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Note that the first argument of an `__init__()` is supposed to be `self`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override a class \_\_init\_\_ method while keeping the types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75070946/how-to-override-a-class-init-method-while-keeping-the-types)

Comment: The first sentence is partly incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77155115/edit) it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)