# inheriting all __init__ arguments' type hints from parent class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, type-hinting, init

**note**: my question could be duplicated or nonessential, or I could even be wrong the whole time. but I couldn't search it because it was a rabbit hole and I need someone's advice.

Hi, it's my first time working with inheritance from other modules and classes made by other. and as so whenever I make a subclass that inherit from a well-defined class like `tkinter.Frame`, `pandas.Dataframe` or `sqlite3.Connection` I get all the arguments with there type-hints (*I'm using `vscode` and by pressing `tab` it autocomplete `def __init_` and generates them*). but the type-hits are always broken, especially the Ellipsis `...`.

I know it can be solved by importing the type-hints *if there exists `TypeVar`, or `TypeAlias` for it*, or remove them altogether, or even remove all the extra-arguments that I don't really need and use `*args, **kwargs` instead.

But I don't want that

I want my subclass to function the same way as the superclass did, and Only extend its functionality. and I found that explicate arguments with there type-hints makes it better to work with class and what it can do.

**example:**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class MyFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master: tkinter.Misc | None = ..., *, border: tkinter._ScreenUnits = ...,
        borderwidth: tkinter._ScreenUnits = ..., class_: str = ..., cursor: tkinter._Cursor = ...,
        height: tkinter._ScreenUnits = ..., name: str = ..., padding: _Padding = ...,
        relief: tkinter._Relief = ..., style: str = ..., takefocus: tkinter._TakeFocusValue = ...,
        width: tkinter._ScreenUnits = ...) -> None:
    
        super().__init__(master, border, borderwidth, class_, cursor, height, name,
                        padding, relief, style, takefocus, width)
```

in this example all ellipsis cause problems and some type-hints don't show up. `_Padding` for example.

and running the a normal code with this class raise this error:

`AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute '_ScreenUnits'`
or
`AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute '_Cursor'`

and if I decided to remove all type-hints, I would get this error because of the ellipsis.
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "ellipsis") to str` *meaning that `...` is getting passed as `str` value*

as I said, I know I could fix it in other ways, but **is there an easy way to inherit the type-hints from the superclass, without breaking my code?**

**or am I doing something wrong??**

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you :)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Callable

_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_T = TypeVar("_T")

def inherit_signature_from(
    _to: Callable[_P, _T]
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., _T]], Callable[_P, _T]]:
    """Set the signature checked by pyright/vscode to the signature of another function."""
    return lambda x: x  # type: ignore


class MyFrame(ttk.Frame):
    @inherit_signature_from(ttk.Frame.__init__)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        # do stuff?
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

VSCode will now think `MyFrame.__init__` has the same signature/arguments as `ttk.Frame.__init__` and will check them accordingly.

Comment: If you want to *add* more arguments check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072701/12020853) on a similar question